# Can you build stand-alone Apache Pivot application, i.e. not run in browser?

Tags: apache-pivot

Can you build stand-alone Apache Pivot application, i.e. not run in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DesktopApplicationContext.main(UI.class, args);
}
```